# Linq select where date is yesterday

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime

I've got as far as this:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
YesterdaysRegistrations = db.tblForumAuthors.Where(c => c.Join_date == yesterday).Count();
```

There definitely records that have the join date of yesterday, but this returns 0 all the time!  Can anyone tell me if I'm doing this correctly?

Comment: Are those `Join_date` fields stored with the time of joining or just the date?

Comment: @Lasse, they have the time as well but I don't know how to strip that in the linq statement

Comment: Can you just do `c.Join_date.Date` to strip off the time and compare, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AddDays` keeps the Hour/Minute/Second components. You either have to use (if c.Join_date is only the date component):

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date;
```

Otherwise, you compare for range:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date;
DateTime yesterdayEnd = DateTime.Today.Date.AddSeconds(-1);
db.tblForumAuthors.Where(c => c.Join_date >= yesterday && c.Join_date < yesterdayEnd)
```

Comment: What if someone joined half a second before midnight? You don't need to subtract the second.

Comment: Thanks but no luck, the field in the DB has time as well which I guess is stopping it working?

Comment: Not true. If the database saves only the date component, Hour/Minute/Second will be 0 on both objects, which is evaluates to true.

Comment: Ahh I can do .date on the field as well, works a charm, thanks!

Comment: The comment to my question comment on the original post indicates that it stores the time.

Comment: @Femar, the DB stored time as well, but doing .Date on both works great thanks!

Comment: No, you can't, this won't work with linq-to-sql. You'll have to use the second way via the range. This is the same in entity framework as well - I started using explicit date fields in the database to work around that. Better than checking for the range everytime.

Comment: @Femar should it not work?  Because it works great at the moment :S

Comment: Did you let it run? The error only appears at runtime. Dunno, maybe it was fixed or it was only in EF. If that's the case, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to strip off the time, you just have to make sure you don't do an exact match.

Try this instead:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // read once, avoid "odd" errors once in a blue moon
DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
YesterdaysRegistrations = db.tblForumAuthors.Where(
    c => c.Join_date >= yesterday
      && c.Join_date < today).Count();
```